# Using CSV with google charts

Tags: javascript, csv, google-visualization

I'm trying to use a CSV file with Google charts to embed it to my website. This is my code:

//UPDATE! This is my new code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
<script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {
        $.get("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=0Ao6fMN9Cw0GPdFVtZ29iYmd1cmRORU0yemYxUjE3OVE&single=true&gid=0&output=csv", function(csvString) {
        var arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
            view.setColumns([0,1]);
        var options =   {
            hAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(0), minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max},
            vAxis: {title: data.getColumnLabel(1), minValue: data.getColumnRange(1).min, maxValue: data.getColumnRange(1).max},
            legend: 'none'
            }
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Where´s the problem? Thx for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You are pulling the following content from google spreadsheet in csv format:

```
,
Jochen,2
Peter,5
Hans,2
Detlef,3
JĂĽrgen,4
Andreas,6
Martin,3
```

That is valid csv format but cannot be used for scatter diagram (you are calling `google.visualization.ScatterChart()` method). With scatter diagram you need something like:

```
'Age','Weight'
8,12
4,5.5
11,14
4,5
3,3.5
6.5,7
```

See [example at jsBin](http://jsbin.com/AnuNoCOq/1/). It will not work there because there is no csv file. Copy code from there and prepare `testchart.csv` which use `Age, Weight` data.

And, it won't work locally just loading html page. You need to start it remotely from server or locally from wamp server.

The result of this example:
[image]

Comment: Thx for your answer. meanwhile, my code looks a bit different (see the update on my first post.

Comment: and I tried your exampe, but it didn´t work on my local wamp server :/